# How to change popup background Color and height in SwiftUi

Tags: swiftui

*Firstly,I created a drop-down menu, then I moved it to the part I created for the login screen earlier. However, the drop-down menu opens as shown in the picture.*

[image: Result]

**But I want the drop down menu to open over the text fields below as in the second photo. How can I do that?**

[image: The image I want to create]

```
struct CountryCodeDropdown: View {
    
    //PROPERTIES
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    @State private var selectedNum = 1
    @State private var isScrollExpanded = false
    @State private var selectedScrollNum = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
        DisclosureGroup("\(selectedScrollNum)", isExpanded: $isScrollExpanded)  {
            ScrollView{
               VStack{
                
                ForEach(1...50,id:\.self){ code in
                    Text("\(code)")
                        .font(Font.custom("Barlow-Regular", size: 12))
                        .padding(.all)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.selectedScrollNum = code
                            withAnimation{
                                self.isScrollExpanded.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                }//foreach
             }//VSTACK
            }.frame( height:50)
            
             
            
          }//Disclosure
        .accentColor(.black)
        .font(Font.custom("Barlow-Regular", size: 17))
        .padding(.trailing)
       
        
     Spacer()
           
        }.frame(height:70)
       
        
    }
}
```

*Login Page*
*Then I put the dropdown menu I created on the login screen.*

```
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3){
            
             HStack{
               
                //CODE
                ZStack {
                    VStack{
                    CountryCodeDropdown()
                        .padding(.top,40)
                   
                        Divider()
                            .padding(.top,-40)
                    } .frame(width: 100)
                    .padding(.leading)
                }
                
                
                
                //PHONE
                CustomTextField(title: "Phone", value: $model.phone, animation: animation)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }//:HSTACK
            Text("OR")
                .padding(.leading)
                .padding(.top,4)
                .font(Font.custom("Barlow-Regular", size: 12))
            
            CustomTextField(title: "E-mail", value: $model.email, animation: animation)
                .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
            
        }//:VSTACK
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working correctly, the only problem is that the height of the ScrollView is too low in `CountryCodeDropdown`. Use a higher number in `.frame(height: 50)`. something like `.frame(height: 250)`.

Comment: When I increase the height, when the dropdown is turned on, it slides up and overlaps the mail. Also I just want to give a color when the dropdown is turned on.